Rigging issue, novice
I've been getting this error: "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones", with no answers working from previous threads. I'm receiving this while trying to weight the model I'm rigging for animation automatically. It might just be user error due to inexperience with the software. help would be appreciated.
I also am unable to select specific bones while in weight paint mode to view where the software suggests that the weight should be, in preview.

That sounds like two questions, one on getting the auto weight painting to work, and the other… blender doesn’t ever “suggest” where weighting should be, but to select bones you have to switch to pose or edit mode on the armature.

hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

To fix the "Bone Heat Weighting: failed" error, select your mesh and go into Edit Mode. Press A to select all vertices/edges/faces, then go to top menu Mesh > Clean Up > Decimate Geometry and set the ratio to 0.98.
When you want to select a specific bone in Weight Paint mode, hold down Alt and left-click on the bone you want to select.

thanks, that did it, but now there is a vertex group that isn't bound to a bone, but is correctly selected.
